# Validation of Dropdown list doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

The following is the code for validating a form with radio buttons, text boxes and dropdown list. The javascript for validating radio buttons and textbox works. But the javascript for dropdown doesn't work. Can you tell me what is it that I've done wrong?

Please help!

Thanks in advance.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


function validateForm()
{
var checked = null;
var name1 = document.forms["information"]["firstname"].value;
var n=name1.split(" ");
var name = n[0];
var sex = document.forms["information"]["sex"];
var e = document.getElementById("prof1");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

  if(name == null || name== "")
{
alert('Enter First Name');
    return false;
}
for (var i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
if(sex[i].checked)
{
checked = sex[i];
return true;
}

 }
if (checked == null)
{
alert(' Enter Sex');
return false;
}


if(strUser==0)
{
alert("Enter Profession");
return false;
}   

}


</script>
</head>


<body>

<form name="information" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post"> 

    <text style="color:red">*</text> First Name: <input type="text"   name="firstname"><br><br>

                     Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>



        <text style="color:red">*</text> Sex: <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male
                          <input type="radio" name="sex"   value="Female"> Female <br><br>



        <text style="color:red">*</text> Profession: 

    <select id="prof1">
    <option value="0"> Select </option>
    <option value="1"> Engineer </option>
        <option value="2"> Doctor </option>
    <option value= "3"> Lawyer </option>
    <option value="4"> Others </option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>             






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(sex[i].checked)
{
checked = sex[i];
return true;
}

Remove return true above.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   for ( var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       if (sex[i].checked) {
           checked = sex[i];
           //return true;
       }

   }
   ```

   Uncomment the return true;

The return statement inside the loop return the value and this results to non-execution of code written after this return statement.

2.

```
   if(strUser==0)
```

replace with

```
   if(strUser=="0")
```

Reason :

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp